# Configure lua prosody for localhost only

Tags: testing, binding, lua, localhost

I want to use [prosody](http://prosody.im) or maybe another xmpp server to test my xmpp bot. I want it to only accept connection from the address/localhost(don't want to configure firewall to block access). I would like to know the easiest way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow connections only from the localhost bind the server to 127.0.0.1. Binding it to 0.0.0.0 will allow connections from any host.

Check http://prosody.im/doc/configure and change the c2s_interface and s2s_interface values to "127.0.0.1"

To allow connections from somewhere else also but not everywhere, you need configure your firewall to do this.

Answer (score 1):

My prosody.cfg.lua thanks to Tuomas

```
-- Prosody XMPP Server Configuration
-- 
-- If it wasn't already obvious, -- starts a comment, and all 
-- text after it on a line is ignored by Prosody.
--
-- The config is split into sections, a global section, and one 
-- for each defined host that we serve. You can add as many host 
-- sections as you like.
--
-- Lists are written { "like", "this", "one" } 
-- Lists can also be of { 1, 2, 3 } numbers, etc. 
-- Either commas, or semi-colons; may be used
-- as seperators.
--
-- A table is a list of values, except each value has a name. An 
-- example table would be:
--
-- ssl = { key = "keyfile.key", certificate = "certificate.cert" }
--
-- Whitespace (that is tabs, spaces, line breaks) is mostly insignificant, so 
-- can 
-- be placed anywhere
-- that     you deem fitting.
--
-- Tip: You can check that the syntax of this file is correct when you have finished
-- by running: luac -p /etc/prosody/prosody.cfg.lua
-- If there are any errors, it will let you know what and where they are, otherwise it 
-- will keep quiet.
--
-- Good luck, and happy Jabbering!

-- Global settings go in this section
-- (ie. those that apply to all hosts)

Host "*"
    c2s_interface = "127.0.0.1"
    s2s_interface = "127.0.0.1"

    -- This is a (by default, empty) list of accounts that are admins 
    -- for the server. Note that you must create the accounts separately
    -- (see http://prosody.im/doc/creating_accounts for info)
    -- Example: admins = { "user1@example.com", "user2@example.net" }
    admins = { }

    -- This is the list of modules Prosody will load on startup.
    -- It looks for mod_modulename.lua in the plugins folder, so make sure that exists too.
    modules_enabled = {
            -- Generally required
                "roster"; -- Allow users to have a roster. Recommended ;)
                "saslauth"; -- Authentication for clients and servers. Recommended if you want to log in.
                "tls"; -- Add support for secure TLS on c2s/s2s connections
                "dialback"; -- s2s dialback support
                "disco"; -- Service discovery

            -- Not essential, but recommended
                "private"; -- Private XML storage (for room bookmarks, etc.)
                "vcard"; -- Allow users to set vCards

            -- Nice to have
                "legacyauth"; -- Legacy authentication. Only used by some old clients and bots.
                "version"; -- Replies to server version requests
                "uptime"; -- Report how long server has been running
                "time"; -- Let others know the time here on this server
                "ping"; -- Replies to XMPP pings with pongs
                "pep"; -- Enables users to publish their mood, activity, playing music and more
                "register"; -- Allow users to register on this server using a client and change passwords

            -- Required for daemonizing, and logging
                "posix"; -- POSIX functionality, sends server to background, enables syslog, etc.

            -- Other specific functionality
                --"console"; -- telnet to port 5582 (needs console_enabled = true)
                --"bosh"; -- Enable BOSH clients, aka "Jabber over HTTP"
                --"httpserver"; -- Serve static files from a directory over HTTP
              };

    -- These modules are auto-loaded, should you
    -- for (for some mad reason) want to disable
    -- them then uncomment them below
    modules_disabled = {
            -- "presence";
            -- "message";
            -- "iq";
    };

    -- Disable account creation by default, for security
    -- For more information see http://prosody.im/doc/creating_accounts
    allow_registration = false;

    -- These are the SSL/TLS-related settings. If you don't want
    -- to use SSL/TLS, you may comment or remove this
    ssl = { 
        key = "/etc/prosody/certs/localhost.key";
        certificate = "/etc/prosody/certs/localhost.cert";
        }

    -- Hint: If you create a new log file or rename them, don't forget to update the
    --       logrotate config at /etc/logrotate.d/prosody
    log = {
        -- Log all error messages to prosody.err
        { levels = { min = "error" }, to = "file", filename = "/var/log/prosody/prosody.err" };
        -- Log everything of level "info" and higher (that is, all except "debug" messages)
        -- to prosody.log
        { levels = { min =  "info" }, to = "file", filename = "/var/log/prosody/prosody.log" };
    }

    pidfile = "/var/run/prosody/prosody.pid"

-- This allows clients to connect to localhost.
-- Obviously this domain cannot normally be accessed from other servers.
Host "localhost"
```